# Scheme concatenate strings to display

Tags: user-interface, scheme, concatenation, racket

I am using DrRacket, version 6.4, English to create a small application in Scheme.
I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to concatenate the following code.
[it works I am just not sure if it is the cleanest since I am new to Scheme]

```
    (display "Rolling ")
    (display (number->string (- 5 (length my-rolled-dice))))
    (display " dice\n")
    (display "You rolled\n")
    (define my-roll (make-list-of-random-numbers (- 5 (length my-rolled-dice) ) 6))
    (display my-roll)
    (display "\n")
```

I am looking for the following output to the screen

```
Rolling 5 dice
You rolled
(3 1 3 6 6)
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this or is this as clean as it gets in Scheme?

Comment: Note that Racket is not the same as scheme; it's very similar and is heavily influenced by it, but not compatible with the scheme standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `printf`, it's shorter:

```
(printf "Rolling ~a dice~n" (- 5 (length my-rolled-dice)))
(printf "You rolled~n~a" (make-list-of-random-numbers (- 5 (length my-rolled-dice)) 6))
```

Comment: Note that it's [more Lispy to use `~%`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cab.htm) instead of `~n`, so I tend to prefer that to be kinder to others. But if your code isn't intended for reading by anyone other than Racketeers, then `~n` is of course fine.

Comment: `printf` is not part of scheme standard, so this doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: @xdavidliu it does answer the question, the question is tagged as “racket” and does not require a standard scheme solution.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez You are right it is tagged as racket, but both the title and the question body specifically ask how to do it in Scheme, not Racket. I guess this is an issue with the question itself.

Comment: @xdavidliu The tag takes precedence, that's how Stack Overflow normally works. Trust me on this one ;)

Answer (score 5):

In Racket, `printf` works, but in Scheme, like MIT-Scheme, there is no `printf`. In that case you can use `map` and `display`. For example:

```
(map display
 (list "Rolling " (- 5 (length my-rolled-dice))
       " dice\nYou rolled\n" my-roll "\n"))
```